# Tikz legend entry image - wrong line angle

Tags: tikz-pgf, legend, line, ybar

I have a ybar tikzpicture with one horizontal line to mark a threshold.

Unfortunately this line does not appear as a horizontal but as a somehow diagonal line in the legend.

I tried some solutions by using \addlegendimage but I didn't manage to get a simple horizontal line.

Below you'll find my graph and the latex code. I hope, it's al clear.

Can someone please help me out?

If there are any questions, please feel free to ask!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Matze

[image: wrong legend image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [
            title = \Large{\textbf{Überprüfung Alarmauslösung}},
            legend style = {at = {(1,1)}, xshift=0.2cm, yshift=0cm, anchor=north west, nodes=right},
            x tick label style={
                /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
            ylabel = gemessene Spannung,
            xlabel = Sensor Nr. in 4 Messungen,
            ybar,
            ymin = 0, ymax = 2.5,
            bar width = 7pt,
            xtick={1, 2, 3, 4},
            xmin = 1, xmax = 4,
            enlarge x limits = 0.2,
        ]
        
            
        
            \addplot[blue!50, fill=blue!50]
            coordinates {(1,2.02) (2,2.05) (3,2.08) (4,2.03)};
            \addlegendentry{$Messung~1$}
            
            \addplot[green!50, fill=green!50]
            coordinates {(1,1.8) (2,1.85) (3,1.9) (4,1.82)};
            \addlegendentry{$Messung~2$}
            
            \addplot[red!50, fill=red!50]
            coordinates {(1,1.84) (2,1.87) (3,1.91) (4,1.86)};
            \addlegendentry{$Messung~3$}
            
            \addplot[orange!50, fill=orange!50]
            coordinates {(1,1.89) (2,1.88) (3,1.93) (4,1.86)};
            \addlegendentry{$Messung~4$}
            
            \addplot[red, sharp plot] 
            coordinates {(0,1.743) (1,1.743) (2,1.743) (3,1.743) (4,1.743) (5,1.743)};    
            
            \addlegendimage{no markers, red}
            \addlegendentry{$Alarmschwelle$}
            
            
    
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Completely unrelated: You definitely don't want to write Messung and Alarmschwelle in math mode, use `\addlegendentry{Messung 1}` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: screenshot]

I created a new style called `line legend 2` below

```
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/line legend 2/.style={
legend image code/.code={\draw[thick] (0cm,0cm)--(.25cm,0cm);},},}
```

by modifying the one given in the manual `/pgfplots/line legend` below

> ```
> \pgfplotsset{
> /pgfplots/line legend/.style={
> legend image code/.code={
> \draw [mark repeat=2,mark phase=2,##1]
> plot coordinates {
> (0cm,0cm)
> (0.3cm,0cm)
> (0.6cm,0cm)
> };
> },
> },
> }
> ```

The code is commented by `%<--`

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/line legend 2/.style={%<-- new style "line legend 2"
legend image code/.code={\draw[thick] (0cm,0cm)--(.25cm,0cm);},},}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        [   legend pos=outer north east,
            title = \Large{\textbf{Überprüfung Alarmauslösung}},
%            legend style = {at = {(1,1)}, xshift=0.2cm, yshift=0cm, anchor=north west, nodes=right},
            x tick label style={
                /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
            ylabel = gemessene Spannung,
            xlabel = Sensor Nr. in 4 Messungen,
            ybar,
            ymin = 0, ymax = 2.5,
            bar width = 7pt,
            xtick={1, 2, 3, 4},
            xmin = 1, xmax = 4,
            enlarge x limits = 0.2,
        ]
        
            \addplot[blue!50, fill=blue!50]
            coordinates {(1,2.02) (2,2.05) (3,2.08) (4,2.03)};
            \addlegendentry{$Messung~1$}
            
            \addplot[green!50, fill=green!50]
            coordinates {(1,1.8) (2,1.85) (3,1.9) (4,1.82)};
            \addlegendentry{$Messung~2$}
            
            \addplot[red!50, fill=red!50]
            coordinates {(1,1.84) (2,1.87) (3,1.91) (4,1.86)};
            \addlegendentry{$Messung~3$}
            
            \addplot[orange!50, fill=orange!50]
            coordinates {(1,1.89) (2,1.88) (3,1.93) (4,1.86)};
            \addlegendentry{$Messung~4$}
            
            \addplot[red,line legend 2,sharp plot] %<-- lien legend 2
            coordinates {(0,1.743) (5,1.743)};    
            
%            \addlegendimage{no markers,red}
            \addlegendentry{$Alarmschwelle$}
            
            
    
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, the 2 doesn't change anything at all, it's just to give a new name to this new style different from `line legend`, I could very well have called this style `my style`.

Comment: Ok - it turns out, that it was me being stupid - I overlooked, that you defined it yourself. -not strange, that I can not find it in the manual.

Comment: It's not your fault. The problem is I don't speak English very well. You can correct my English in my answer so that other users can better understand what I mean. I'm sorry if I misspoke.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndréC!
This solved my problem perfectly!

Just one last question: Why did you change `legend style = {at = {(1,1)}, xshift=0.2cm, yshift=0cm, anchor=north west, nodes=right},` into `legend pos=outer north east,`?

Comment: @Matze You are welcome

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment while you were already answering: Just one last question: `Why did you change legend style = {at = {(1,1)}, xshift=0.2cm, yshift=0cm, anchor=north west, nodes=right},` into `legend pos=outer north east,`?

Comment: @Matze Because this option does the same thing `legend pos=outer north east`

Comment: okay, but not exactly. _Messung 1_ to _4_ get shifted a little bit more to the right while _Alarmschwelle_ stays left.

Comment: @Matze Oh, that's right, I hadn't noticed that difference.